# Prevent or Capture MouseWheel scrolling on DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I'm trying to capture the mousewheel event on a Silverlight 4 DataGrid. The problem is that whenever the mousewheel event is handled by the DataGrid the MouseWheel event does not fire. But when the DataGrid is at the top and I try to scroll upwards I get the MouseWheel event and the same thing at the bottom - i.e. the event is fired when the DataGrid does not handle the MouseWheel event itself.

I've also tried to capture the mousewheel event on the vertical ScrollBar (the Silverlight DataGrid does not use a ScrollViewer)

1. How can I prevent the scrolling?
2. If I don't prevent the scrolling - how can I capture the event in all scenarios?
3. Can I capture MouseWheel events even though I haven't focused the DataGrid yet (the event does not fire and the scrolling does not work before focusing the DataGrid)? Or should I use the following events:

   HtmlPage.Window.AttachEvent("DOMMouseScroll", OnMouseWheel);
   HtmlPage.Window.AttachEvent("onmousewheel", OnMouseWheel);
   HtmlPage.Document.AttachEvent("onmousewheel", OnMouseWheel);

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prevent scrolling you could derive from the DataGrid and override OnMouseWheel.

```
public class MyDataGrid :DataGrid
    {
        protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

If you want to get ALL events on a UIElement you can do this with the AddHandler method where you can set a flag to get even the handled events. Here's an example:

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.RootVisual.AddHandler(MouseWheelEvent, new MouseWheelEventHandler(MyHandler), true);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        void MyHandler(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs args)
        {

        }
```

I hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Comment: Why would you add a handler actually in the OnMouseWheel event of a UIElement? The user scrolls the wheel 3 times how many handlers have been added?

Comment: Hi, this was just an example. I know that it is total nonsense to add the handler there ;) But you are right, the next time I have to provide a better example.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Works perfectly. Maybe you have the final piece to my puzzle... I have a ScrollViewer and I catch the MouseWheel event for it - that's working fine. But if I mousewheel over the (vertical) ScrollBar of the ScrollViewer - then the ScrollBar will handle the event and I can't prevent it. Since ScrollViewer is sealed I can't inherit my "CustomScrollViewer" from it and override the OnMouseWheel action as above. Do you have any suggestion on how to prevent the MouseWheel event on the ScrollBar of the ScrollViewer? :)